# PHP Convert single dimensional array to nested array

Tags: php, arrays, nested

How do I convert an 'N' elements single dimensional array to 'N' level nested array in PHP ?

Example:

**Input:**

```
$input = array('Orange','Apple','Banana');
```

**Expected Output:**

```
$output = array(
    'name' => 'Banana',
    'sub_category' => array(
         'name' => 'Apple',
         'sub_category' => array(
             'name' => 'Orange'
);
```

**This is my code:**

```
  $categories = array('Orange','Apple','Banana');
  $count = count($categories);
  for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
    if(isset($categories[$i+1])){
      $parent = $categories[$i+1]; // parent      
        $categories[$i+1]=array(
          'name' => $categories[$i+1],
          'sub_category' => array('name' => $categories[$i])
        );
    }   
  }
  $categories = $categories[$count-1];
  var_dump($categories);
```

My code is sloppy and I also get the following incorrect output:

```
$output = array(
    'name' => 'Banana',
    'sub_category' => array(
       'name' => array(  
         'name' => 'Apple',
         'sub_category' => array(
             'name' => 'Orange'
       );
);
```

Edit 1:

The problem/solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174787/convert-non-nested-and-bracketed-array-to-nested-array) does not seem to be answering my question.

Comment: How do you want to determine multiple sub categories? Is the output supposed to be from the last element being the parent and every subsequent one being a sub category of the previous element?

Comment: Yes. Correct. The last element is the super parent and the ones preceding it is its sub-category.

Comment: You could use simple recursion technique: `function toNestedArray(array $input, array $result = []) {
    $result = ['name' => array_pop($input)];
    
    if (count($input)) {
        $result['sub_category'] = toNestedArray($input, $result);
    }
    
    return $result;
}`

Comment: @jay-blanchard Question sounds similar to the duplicate, but it is not what the OP was asking.

Comment: Thanks a lot @x3ns. Your solution works perfectly. Recursion is the key.

Comment: @x3ns Post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use simple recursion technique:

```
function toNestedArray(array $input, array $result = [])
{
    $result = ['name' => array_pop($input)];
    if (count($input)) {
        $result['sub_category'] = toNestedArray($input, $result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to loop over the `$input` array, building the `$output` array from inside to out.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $name) {
    if (empty($output)) {
        $output = array("name" => $name);
    } else {
        $output = array("name" => $name, "sub_category" => $output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = array('Orange','Apple','Banana');
  $count = count($categories);
  $categories2=array();
  for($i=$count-1;$i>0;$i--){
      if($i-2>-1){

          $categories2=array(
          'name'=>$categories[$i],
          'sub_category'=>array('name'=>$categories[$i-1],'sub_categories'=>array('name'=>$categories[$i-2]))
          ); 
      }
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($categories2);
  echo "</pre>";
```